# How to initialize servletContext in junit test

Tags: tomcat

In my project, I initialized configuration data in ServletContext, then I can read data from memory, and it worked well, but now I wrote some junit tests, it can not initialized ServletContext. can you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need not initialize configuration data in `servletContext`, you can use A static variable to store configuration data, and when you start server you can initialized it.
For setting up a full `WebApplicationContext` in a test environment, you can use `XmlWebApplicationContext` (or `GenericWebApplicationContext`), passing in an appropriate `MockServletContext` instance.
You might want to configure your`MockServletContext` with a `FileSystemResourceLoader` in that case, to make your resource paths interpreted as relative file system locations.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to mock servlet:[How to mock servlet in spring mvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html), but I think you need not initialize configuration data in servletContext, you can use A static variable to store configuration data, and when you start server you can initialized it. the code is as follows:

```
public class InitProperties {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InitProperties.class);

public static Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public static void initProperties(){
    String filePath = FilePathConstant.XXX_CONF;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        props.load(in);

        Set keySet = props.keySet();

        for(Object o: keySet){
            propertiesMap.put(o.toString(), props.getProperty(o.toString()).toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Read property value by key failed!", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Close inputStream failed!", e);
        }

    }
}
```

}

you just need call the method`InitProperties.initProperties()` when you start server, and then you can read configuration data from `InitProperties.propertiesMap`.